# Giving formula to a cell which has Unknown Range [ERROR]

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, range

I'm basically trying to give a formula to a cell including unknown range. But I'm keep getting error. "inpt1" changes according to inpt1's count so I cannot formulate that. As inpt1 changes I cannot control the sum formula due to its range changes as well. Let me illustrate;

```
Cells(inpt1 + 3, 4).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(inpt1 + 2, 9)) & ")"
```

I added an example image for you guys to understand it better.

[Try to sum the prices of I3:I5 & write it as a formula in green area in the picture](https://i.hizliresim.com/LDJ0rz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
Cells(inpt1 + 3, 4).Formula = "=SUM(I9:I" & inpt1 + 2 & ")"
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a string to the Formula.

Currently:

> `Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(inpt1 + 2, 9))`

Is trying to return a variant array to the formula string.  A variant array cannot be converted to a string.

You want the address string.  To get that we add `.Address` to the end of the Range:

```
Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(inpt1 + 2, 9)).Address
```